# TweetSharp SendTweetWithMediaOptions example

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter, tweetsharp

Anyone here tried tweeting with an image using TweetSharp?

I tried the following:

```
Dictionary<string, Stream> imageDict = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
imageDict.Add(imagePath, imageStream);
// I'm getting an error with the line below.
// It's saying I have some invalid arguments. :(
status = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions() { Status = readerMsg.Message, Images = imageDict });
```

But the last line is giving me an invalid argument error with no helpful reason why.

I tried looking at their [GitHub](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) page but the sample only illustrates how to post a simple text message.

Comment: See the first part of this pull request.. 
https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/pull/65/files
calling `SendTweetWithMedia` instead of `SendTweet` may be the issue. Also, the key in the dictionary, doesn't seems to be the image path (you're giving it a `Stream` anyway) example passes "test" to it. --HTH

Comment: That worked! Thanks for pointing out the SendTweet error. Create an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: posted.. see below.
 -Thanks-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the first part of this pull request: [TweetSharp Github](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/pull/65/files)

calling `SendTweetWithMedia` instead of SendTweet may be the case.

Also, the key in the dictionary, doesn't seems to be the image path (you're giving it a Stream anyway) example passes "test" to it.

--HTH
Have fun

Answer (score 1):

`service.SendTweet()` accepts parameter of type `SendTweetOptions`, If you want to post images you can use

```
service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions 
{ 
     Status = "message", 
     Images = dictionary 
}
);
```